# Confusing 受け身 questions

Tags: passive-voice

I am looking at the following problem:

> 自分の考えに自信を持ち、これで良いのだと自分に言いきかせるだけは充分ではない。他の人の考えにも、肯定的な姿勢を(  　)しなくてはならない。どんなものでもその気になって探せば、必ずいいところがある。それを称揚する....

The four possible answers are :

```
a. とるように 
b. とられるように
c. とらせるように
d. とらされるように
```

The book says the answer is とるように. Why doesn't the 受け身 work？

`他の人の考えにも、肯定的な姿勢をとるようにしなくてはならない`-> we have to adopt another person positive attitude and consider what they think(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the subject is "we", not 肯定的な姿勢.

If the phrase is 肯定的な姿勢が, so 肯定的な姿勢 is a subject, it become passive form like 肯定的な姿勢がとられるように.

Comment: ようにしなくてはならない->is this ようにする？ or ように/しなければならない？

Comment: I think it is the latter.